# How can the Linux kernel's ciphers be used from Ruby?

Tags: ruby, linux, encryption, linux-kernel, openssl

The Linux kernel has a cryptographic API that uses cipher names described like `aes-xts-plain64` and `aes-cbc-essiv:sha256` (these examples are the default ciphers used by the Linux `cryptsetup` tool). The names comprise

- a *cipher* : `aes`
- a *mode* : `xts`
- a method to generate an *initialisation vector* : `plain64`

These descriptions differ from OpenSSL which uses a different format. You can list the openSSL ones with `openssl list-cipher-commands` and the available ciphers loaded in the current kernel can be seen with `cat /proc/crypto`.

#### Given data encrypted by the kernel API, can it be decrypted using Ruby?

I can think of two approaches to this problem: use Ruby bindings to either the kernel's Crypto API or OpenSSL.

I have tried both approaches. I have not been able to find a way to use the kernel API from Ruby. I have used OpenSSL but it isn't clear how to translate the kernel's cipher string into one that OpenSSL understands.

Comment: It seems to me that `aes-128-xts` is part of OpenSSL and should be usable from ruby because of that. Have you tried it?

Comment: It is indeed and it works but there were other apsects of the configuration that were causing me problems, specifically setting the initialisation vector and how I was iterating over the source data. It would be good to learn how, if possible, to use the kernel API from Ruby though -- if nothing else just to learn something new.

Comment: Please show what you've tried including input/output vectors to decrypt values from the kernel API. The current way your question is stated, it comes down to us doing all the research.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear - I have it working fine using the Ruby OpenSSL library. The details that were missing were implementation-specific and I have sorted them out now. I haven't been able to use the Kernel API from Ruby as I don't know how to do it (I don't know if such a Ruby library exists). When I say it's working, I mean that I have it working with OpenSSL. What I would still be interested in is how to use the kernel API from Ruby but that is purely from the perspective of wanting to learn something new.